# (Scribus) Generate one pdf file directly or create more and merge into one at the end?

Tags: publishing, scribus

I want to write a book and I want to write different chapters with different topics in Scribus.
Each topic is given to some readers before the book is printed (for corrections and so on)

What is better?
Generate 1 pdf file from the original source file at the end and use this?

Or merge the different topics as pdf files to one pdf file and also have one source file for each topic (easier to correct and manage and make changes?)

Merging is done with the commandline tool PDFMerger from Apaches PDFBox http://pdfbox.apache.org/

Comment: You might want to look into [portfolios](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/9.0/Standard/WSA2872EA8-9756-4a8c-9F20-8E93D59D91CE.html)

Comment: well I can not and dont want to use portfolios. Also I think this is just supported by Adobe PDF / Acrobat and not Scribus

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Both options seem rather trivial to me, but the merging can be done easier.